# Wrong DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH variable

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

When importing data model from external service which in this case is an xsodata source, I see that the VDM creates a wrong DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH. Indeed the original service contains a "." inside like this "/xsodata/Internals.xsodata/$metadata", 
[image]
but when checking the service generated by the VDM when importing data from external service in SAP Web IDE, I see this:
String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "/xsodata/Internalsxsodata";
without the "."
[image]
I had to add the "." manually.

Could you please check?

Simmaco

Comment: Thanks for the great question. Just for clarity, what version of the SDK do you use? We're are already looking into this and hope to get back soon.

Comment: In the POM I have the following dependency:   <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.servicesdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata-v2-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.38.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>

Comment: Can you please download the EDMX file from "/xsodata/Internals.xsodata/$metadata" and check whether attribute `href` of element `//Schema/link[@rel="self"]` contains a dot `.` in the URL or not?

Comment: Service SDK is a bit different thing, can you look for this [dependency's version](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sap.cloud.sdk*%20AND%20v:3.14.0).

Comment: @AlexanderDümont There is no such element in my EDMX file.

Comment: @ArtyomKovalyov This is what I see as "sdk-modules-bom"  <dependency >
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana</groupId>
    <artifactId>sdk-modules-bom</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.0</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
   </dependency>

Comment: The following term cannot be found in the EDMX...? `rel="self"` I'm asking because in the generator source code, there is no manipulation happening for the service endpoint path. That's why I assume a "wrong" declaration in the EDMX file itself.

Comment: So what exactly do you want me to do?

Comment: Can you please upload or send me the EDMX file to my company email address? :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the manual change of the service EDMX file is not possible and you don't want to repeatedly adjust the generated source file(s), then I would recommend the `#withServicePath` method when interacting the service instance, e.g.:

```java
InternalxsodataService service = new DefaultInternalxsodataService()
  .withServicePath("xsodata/internals.xsodata");
```